# How to make each bar clickable in a graph in perl

Tags: perl, perl-module

I have generated a graph. On click of each bar in the graph, I should be able to generate another graph. I am using GD::Graph module. If its not possible to make the bars clickable, is there a way where I can click the x-axis values at least? Thank you.

Comment: What is the output? I thought GD-based modules are restricted to making files, and only files.

Answer (score 1):

If you want user interaction, I believe you need to work with a GUI toolkit such as [Prima](http://www.prima.eu.org/) ([CPAN link](http://search.cpan.org/~karasik/Prima/Prima.pm)), [Gtk2](http://gtk2-perl.sourceforge.net/) ([CPAN link](http://search.cpan.org/~xaoc/Gtk2-1.242/lib/Gtk2.pm)), or something else. (Note the [Qt](http://perlqt.sourceforge.net/) bindings are old and I am not sure they work these days.) For exampe, I don't think it would be too difficult to create an image file with GD::Graph and then [load it into Prima](http://search.cpan.org/~karasik/Prima/pod/Prima/image-load.pod). You'd have to write your own MouseDown routines, which might go beyond your skill or interest, but I think this is the only way (currently) to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with David, you need to make output which is clickable. If you are using a web interface then perhaps rather than generating an image via GD you need to create a Canvas plot using a javascript library. There are pleny to choose from. A quick search turned up [highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/) for example.

If you are making a non-browser GUI then David has you covered.